# How to disable wide right click context menus in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, context-menu, windows-10-preview

Upgraded to Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview build 10537
The spacing between items in the new context menu is too big and too difficult to use when there are a lot of items

Is there a way to reduce the spacing in between items of the Right Click context menu to reduce the vertical size of the context menu?

Screenshot:

[image: Before / After Screenshot]

Comment: this is a new features of this build to improve touch usage of desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1 - [WinAero Tweaker](http://winaero.com/download.php?view.1796)**

Disable wide context menus in Windows 10 using [WinAero Tweaker](http://winaero.com/download.php?view.1796) by checking the box in below screenshot.

[image: WinAero Tweaker - Wide Context Menus]

**Method 2 - Registry Hack**

1. Open Registry Editor (<kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd> + <kbd>**R**</kbd> and type `regedit`)
2. Go to the following key:

   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\FlightedFeatures`
3. Create a new 32-bit DWORD value named `ImmersiveContextMenu`. Even if you are running 64-bit Windows, you still need to create a 32-bit DWORD value.
4. Leave its value data as 0. See the following screenshot:

[image: ImmersiveContextMenu]

5. Restart the Explorer shell or sign out from Windows 10 and log back in.

**Before / After Screenshot**

[image: Before / After Screenshot]

Information about the tweak and more screenshots can be found [here](http://winaero.com/blog/disable-wide-context-menus-in-windows-10-and-revert-them-to-classic-appearance/), ready-to-use Registry files [here](http://winaero.com/download.php?view.1870) and list of all WinAero Tweaker features [here](http://winaero.com/blog/the-list-of-winaero-tweaker-features/).

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Windows 10 1809 and above.

Download the file in the Google Drive link and follow the instructions.

Welcome to the Classic Context Menu.

Google Drive Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B7Qv4ccxPLUPnKoXCJ8tyAAzUeHCzc10

Screenshot: [image]

Regards, Yasin Karaçivi

Answer (score 0):

Navigate through

- User Configuration,
- Administrative Templates,
- and Windows Components.
- Then, in the Right Pane, click twice on File Explorer.
- Now, scroll down to the bottom and double-click on Remove File Explorer's default context menu.

[image]